# Apache stops responding to requests

Tags: debian, python, apache2

There is a lightly loaded web server. Debian jessie, apache2, python app. 
There is a simple curl script, on the same machine, that sends an alert if apache does not respond. Sometimes apache stops responding, the script stops sending alerts. And after a pause, hundreds of alerts arrive in a row. What can be wrong? Server runs out of sockets?
Can manually updated apache be the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without more information. When debugging problems like this, I always recommend to first look at access and error logs. Should be in /var/log/apache2. Check for entries around the time the server doesn't respond. If there are no entries at all, then I'd think it should be a general system issue and not an apache issue. In this case I'd write a script that monitors system load, memory, and open files to see if there are correlations at times Apache fails to respond.

How are you testing for Apache's response? Are you just getting a timeout? Are you using a url or just the numeric ip address for localhost?

Comment: watch correlations with system load is a good idea. for alerts, I recently set a 20 second timeout for responses from a localhost.